# how to write nhibernate query for this sql statement

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

How can I write a fluent nhibernate query for the below SQL query statement :

```
select iseat.companynr, mdata.Employeenr from IDepartment as iseat inner join 
Employee as i on i.pkey = iseat.employeefk 
inner join employeedata as edata on edata.employeefk = i.pkey
```

I have already created classes `IDepartment` , `Employee` and `Employeedata` and also I have created a class `CompanyNr2EmployeeNrMap` , which contains 2 properties `CompanyNr` and `EmployeeNr`.

The query needs to take a list of companynr as parameters and return a list of `CompanyNr2EmployeeNrMap`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from emp in session.Query<Employee>()
            from department in emp.Departments
            select new CompanyNr2EmployeeNrMap
            {
                CompanyNr = department.CompanyNr,
                EmployeeNr = emp.Data.EmployeeNr
            };

return query.ToList();
```